# Uniqueness of Gibbs Measure on Ising model

Tags: markov-chains, ising-model

If I understood this correctly, the Gibbs Specification for the [Ising model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ising_model#No_phase_transitions_in_finite_volume) on $ℤ^d$ dos not have a unique [Gibbs Measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_measure) for β above the critical level. But what about the Ising model [on a finite lattice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-lattice_Ising_model) $V⊂ℤ^d$?

And if it is not unique for a finite lattice, how is that possible as I can construct a [Gibbs Sampler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_sampling) – a markov chain, that has the measure that fulfills the specification  as its stationary distribution – that is clearly irreducible (we can go from anywhere to the $\{-1\}^V$ state and get everywhere from there) and thus must have an unique stationary distribution?

Comment: Too much to parse to me.

Comment: @WlodzimierzHolsztynski ?

Comment: Your second (last) question is difficult to follow to me. (BTW, it'd be nice to see the relevant definitions. I'd like such definition-oriented spirit in general on MO).

Comment: That stuff is complicated to define – I added some links to Wikipedia if that helps :/. But I think I already [found the answer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ising_model#No_phase_transitions_in_finite_volume) there, even though I am absolutely not happy about that explanation :/.

Comment: I meant not meritum but straight language, simple grammar, ...

Comment: Isn't the Gibbs measure in a finite lattice (at the given temperature) unique by the very definition?

Comment: @WlodzimierzHolsztynski “meritum”? Why would it be unique “by definition”?

Comment: You @Chronial remind me of a Turing secretary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the physics point of view, the answer to your question is an immediate "yes": a nonunique Gibbs measure arises if there is a phase transition into a phase with multiple ground states (say, a phase transition into a ferromagnetic state with all spins aligned either up or down). A finite system has no phase transitions, there is a unique equilibrium state, hence a unique Gibbs measure.

Mathematically, one can also see this from the definition of a nonunique Gibbs measure given, for example, by Dror Weitz, [Combinatorial Criteria for Uniqueness of Gibbs Measures:](http://www.stanford.edu/~montanar/TEACHING/Stat375/papers/weitz1.pdf)

> The question of uniqueness can be viewed combinatorially as comparing
>   two finite distributions (conditioned on two different boundary
>   configurations), and asking whether or not their difference goes to
>   zero as the boundary ball recedes to infinity.